# how do i find text between upper case characters in data frame rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with character strings of upper and lower case values and I need to extract only the lower case values between strings of 3 upper case values.

I'm using python and pandas to do this but have been unsuccessful. This is what the data looks like:

```
afklajrwouoivWERvalueineedREWkfjdsl
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include the code you wrote that doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: Have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] including sample input and output, and code for what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `re` package with the same regex :

```
import re

re.search('[A-Z]{3}(.+?)[A-Z]{3}', s).group()[3:-3]
```

Output :

```
valueineed
```

---

If there are several occurences you should instead use :

```
matches = re.finditer('[A-Z]{3}(.+?)[A-Z]{3}',s)
results = [match.group(1) for match in matches]
```

Comment: thank you, please up vote my question so i can use the site again.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one of them solved your problem. It will also give you a little bit of reputation ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['afklajrwouoivWERvalueineedREWkfjdsl']}, index=[0])

df['text'].str.extract('[A-Z]{3}(.+?)[A-Z]{3}')
```

Output:

```
valueineed
```

Note, this gets all characters between 3 uppercased letters.